# Rewrite rule to mock domain name

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wpml

Is there a way to mock a domain name with another one parked on the same server?

I'm using WordPress with WPML plugin for multilanguage. WPML has an option to use different domain names for different languages, using parked domains. My problem is that I want to have more than one domain name for a specific language. Let's assume that `domain.co.uk`, `domain.us` and `domain.com` should all deliver `EN`, but WPML only allows me to set `domain.com` for `EN`.

Is there a way to trick the server to make it look like a different domain was requested? For example, when I'm accessing: `www.domain.us/some-address/here` I need it to serve the exact same content as `www.domain.com/some-address/here` would, without redirecting.

Thanks!

Comment: Use domain forwarding. Otherwise you get into the mess of duplicate content with Google.

Comment: @Aibrean: Thank you! Duplicated content doesn't seem to be a problem when using different TLD's, as stated by Google Webmasters in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ets7nHOV1Yo How is it any difference betweeen using domain forwarding vs other methods, like mod_rewrite?